# Eclipse Git Configuration System Settings is disabled

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, eclipse-mars

I'm working with Eclipse Mars, on Windows 7 64 bits and I recently discovered that when I clone a repository using eclipse built-in git clone feature, CRLF are not added to the files, and they are cloned with only LF at the end.

I checked Eclipse config for Git (Team > Git > Configuration) and I found that System Settings is empty and all buttons disabled and it says "Unknown" in the Location field.

I have Git for Windows 2.5.0 64 bits installed. Apparently now the system `gitconfig` file should be under `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc` but by default there is no file there.

I discovered that if I manually populate it from cmd (`git config --system core.autocrlf true`) it will be created, but still can't select it from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell EGit where the default system configuration is for it to be able to pick up the values. There's a Browse button which should allow you to change it according to the help pages:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pointing_out_the_System_wide_configuration

You can also set this property in the User Settings which Eclipse will respect. Global is 'for all users of this machine' and User Settings is typically stored in your home directory, i.e. 'for just this user'.

You'd have to find where the file that's being created by `git config --global` on your setup is. It's likely that `git` isn't on the path, and that's why Eclipse can't auto-guess where it should be.

By the way, unless you really, really need to have CRLF on the files you should prefer to keep them as how they are stored remotely - it will be faster for EGit and Git to perform deltas if it doesn't have to do line-ending conversion on most operations.

Comment: thanks for answering. I said in the question that the buttons under System Settings are all disabled, there isn't even a "Browse" button but a disabled "Open" button. And I believe that Git's global config is under my user folder, but what I'm reffering to is Git's system config: "`git config --system`"

Comment: Ok, It was the thing with the path. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also I don't think that to keep cloned files as they were in the remote repo is a good practice for Windows users, since some text editors don't read current line ending of the files they edit and they jsut insert CRLF each time you hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem so let me add this for clarification: in Eclipse Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration the System Settings Tab was empty and "Location:" said "Unknown". The EGit User Guide (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pointing_out_the_System_wide_configuration) tells that "If you selected one of the options to use Git from the Command Line Prompt when you installed Git for Windows, then the location of the system wide settings is filled in with a path and everything is fine. If not, use the Browse button to locate where Git is installed, e.g. C:\Program Files(x86)\Git." Indeed I did not select the option to use "Git from the Command line ..." when I installed Git. But instead of a "Browse" button my Eclipse 2020-09 has an "Open" button and that one was GREYED OUT, so I was unable to tell EGit in the above mentioned "System Settings" Tab where the local Git installation could be found. Furthermore I did not know which path precisely had to be added to the systems PATH variable.
I then reinstalled Git with the option to use "Git from the Command line ..." and found out that "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" was added to the System PATH. After a restart of Eclipse the "System Settings" Tab had the "Location" configured as: "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig" and all the missing keys and corresponding values were set.